# How I can use a method like list.length in function arguments using parameter I just defined without saying variable is not defined

Tags: function, dart, arguments, parameter-passing

I want to create this block of code **work in Dart**

```
int pivot (List list ,[ int start = 0 , int end = list.length ] ) { return 1}
```

this work fine if I wrote syntax like this in JavaScript but when writing it in dart it gives me error that **list** used in **list.length** is ***not defined***.
How can I solve it especially if this function will be used as recursive function so that I can't defined the parameters out of it.

I am returning 1 here to simplify the function logic as I want to focus on the parameter problem.

Comment: `int pivot(List list, [int start = 0, int end = -1]) { if (end == -1) { end = list.length; } ... }`

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks a lot bro, creative solution as I need it only to work and it did,  but my brain only comparing between it and JS so it didn't find out that solution.